# Flutter the gradient does not take all of its container

Tags: flutter, dart, gradient

I'm just trying to make a gradient on a container that takes up the full width and height of the screen. The gradient is applied but not correctly because the distribution of colors over the width is not correct.

Here what I see:

[image]

**Why the green color does not extend to half ?**(Ignore the black bar)

---

Splah_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: double.infinity,
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [Color(0xFFc2e59c), Color(0xFF64b3f4)],
            begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
            end: Alignment.centerRight,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

App_page.dart

```
class AppPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<SidebarProvider>(
              create: (BuildContext context) => SidebarProvider()),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: AppConstant.kAppName,
          theme: ThemeConstant().data,
          home: const SplashPage(),
        ));
  }
}
```

Main.dart

```
void main() async {
  await ErrorsHandler().initialize();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runZonedGuarded<Future<void>>(() async {
    await SystemPreferenceHelper().initialize();
    runApp(const AppPage());
  }, (dynamic error, dynamic stack) async {
    ErrorsHandler().handleUncaughtError(error, stack);
  });
}
```

Comment: It's the same result

Comment: '(Ignore the black bar)' I think this may actually be related to your issue since I cannot reproduce. This code produces fullwidth gradient https://pastebin.com/JThiRRtM https://imgur.com/a/SmgQi7g